# Add different suffix to column names on multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I'm trying to add different suffixes to my data frames so that I can distinguish them after I've merge them. I have my data frames in a list and created a vector for the suffixes but so far I have not been successful.

data2016 is the list containing my 7 data frames

```
new_names <- c("june2016", "july2016", "aug2016", "sep2016", "oct2016", "nov2016", "dec2016")
data2016v2 <- lapply(data2016, paste(colnames(data2016)), new_names)
```

Comment: Can you show us a short version of your `data2016v2`-dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an index number within `lapply` to reference both the list and your vector of suffixes. Because there are a couple steps, I'll wrap the process in a `function()`. (Called an *anonymous function* because we aren't assigning a name to it.)

```
data2016v2 <- lapply(1:7, function(i) {
  this_data <- data2016[[i]] # Double brackets for a list
  names(this_data) <- paste0(names(this_data), new_names[i]) # Single bracket for vector
  this_data # The renamed data frame to be placed into data2016v2
})
```

Notice in the `paste0()` line we are recycling the term in `new_names[i]`, so for example if `new_names[i]` is `"june2016"` and your first `data.frame` has columns `"A"`, `"B"`, and `"C"` then it would give you this:

```
> paste0(c("A", "B", "C"), "june2016")
[1] "Ajune2016" "Bjune2016" "Cjune2016"
```

(You may want to add an underscore in there?)

As an aside, it sounds like you might be better served by adding the `"june2016"` as a column in your data (like say a variable named `month` with `"june2016"` as the value in each row) and combining your data using something like `bind_rows()` from the `dplyr` package, running it "long" instead of "wide".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This is exactly what I was looking for. The problem I'm running into now is ```data2016v3 <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "Employee ID", all = TRUE), data2016v2)``` will no longer work because my merging column is different but I will try to figure this out. Thanks again!!

Comment: Perhaps something like `names(this_data)[-1] <- paste0(names(this_data)[-1], new_names[i])`? If your ID is in the first column, that is.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not quite clear. Therefore two solutions.
The beginning is the same for either solution. Suppose you have these four dataframes:

```
df1x <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(50),
                   v2 = runif(50))
df2x <- data.frame(v3 = rnorm(60),
                   v4 = runif(60))
df3x <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(50),
                   v2 = runif(50))
df4x <- data.frame(v3 = rnorm(60),
                   v4 = runif(60))
```

Suppose further you assemble them in a list, something akin to your `data2016`using `mget`and `ls` and describing a pattern to match them:

```
my_list <-  mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+x$"))
```

The names of the dataframes in this list are the following:

```
names(my_list)
[1] "df1x" "df2x" "df3x" "df4x"
```

**Solution 1**:

Suppose you want to change the names of the dataframes thus:

```
new_names <- c("june2016", "july2016","aug2016", "sep2016")
```

Then you can simply assign `new_names`to `names(my_list)`:

```
names(my_list) <- new_names
```

And the result is:

```
names(my_list)
[1] "june2016" "july2016" "aug2016"  "sep2016"
```

**Solution 2**:

You want to **add** the `new_names` **literally** as suffixes to the 'old' names, in which case you would use `paste`or `paste0` thus:

```
names(my_list) <- paste0(names(my_list), "_", new_names)
```

And the result is:

```
names(my_list)
[1] "df1x_june2016" "df2x_july2016" "df3x_aug2016"  "df4x_sep2016"
```

Comment: You can specify `data2016v2  <- Map(function(dat, y) setNames(dat, 
             paste0(names(dat), y)), data2016, new_names)`

Comment: Another solution provided by @akrun but later withdrawn is this: `data2016v2 <- Map(function(dat, y) setNames(dat, paste0(names(dat), y)), data2016, new_names)`

Comment: I guess now you would admit what the OP wanted